# PHP case not working with integer

Tags: php

I have a strange case issue, in my php code;

```
$sm_hours = (int)$sm_hours;  // Make it an integer

echo $sm_hours;  // is 206

    switch ($sm_hours) {
        case ($sm_hours = 0 && $sm_hours <= 120):
            echo "One";
        break;
        case ($sm_hours >= 121 && $sm_hours <= 240):
            echo "Two";
        break;
        case ($sm_hours >= 241):
            echo "Three";
        break;
    }
```

$sm_hours is 206 but the echo I get is One not Two.  What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: try using intva($sm_hours); instead of casting (int)

Comment: try $sm_hours >= 0 && $sm_hours <=120

Comment: "=" is an assignment operator not comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

You will always jump into the first switch case because you are setting `$sm_hours` to 0. A single `=` is used to set the variable.

To test its value use `==` which will perform [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), or use `===` to test the type also.

Answer (score 1):

```
 case ($sm_hours == 0 && $sm_hours <= 120):
```

you are using equality operator

Answer (score 1):

In case one, try this:

```
case ($sm_hours == 0 && $sm_hours <= 120):
    echo "One";
break;
```

Comment: Great thanks.. I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't see it!

Comment: in this case the first case will only be true if sm_hours is 0

Comment: @HeavyHead it won't work if 0 < $sum_hours < 120 . Try it

Answer (score 1):

Better use if and elseif statements in your case:

```
$sm_hours = (int)$sm_hours;  // Make it an integer
echo $sm_hours;  // is 206

if ($sm_hours >= 0 && $sm_hours <= 120)
    echo "One";
elseif ($sm_hours >= 121 && $sm_hours <= 240)
    echo "Two";
else
    echo "Three";
```

switch just tries to match exact values.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $sm_hours >= 0 && $sm_hours <=120
```

Comment: can you explain, why his code is not working?

Comment: the switch statement gets converted to switch(260(boolean)) as int is a boolean value.In the first statement $variable gets updated to 0 which returns a boolean true and when it is compared with 120 it always evaluate to true as 0 < 120 and hence the boolean value becomes true and a match occurs and hence the condition is evaluated

Comment: I thought you would point to the assignment instead of the comparision here: `sm_hours = 0`

Comment: The solution that the OP has accepted is not logically correct . Consider when the value of variable is less than 120 and > 0 .Logically first condition nets to get accepted but it won't happen and hence it is logically flawed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this works taking into account where $sm_hours is < 120 as pointed out by Anand.  This code works for all options that I need.

```
     switch ($sm_hours) {
        case ($sm_hours >= 121 && $sm_hours <= 240):
            echo "Two";
        break;
        case ($sm_hours >= 241):
            echo "Three";
        break;
        default:
            echo "One";
        break;
     }
```